# node js express error couldn't find views directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, dreamhost

so i have this node js express project that i run (gotten from github not made by me but i understand it ofcourse) when i run it on my localhost it runs exactly as expected however when ran on my website it gives the following error

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "/home/dh_vemh38/thepog.xyz/public/dashboard/templates/index.ejs" in views directory "/home/dh_vemh38/thepog.xyz/public/views"
    at Function.render (/home/dh_vemh38/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:580:17)
    at ServerResponse.render (/home/dh_vemh38/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1012:7)
    at renderTemplate (/home/dh_vemh38/thepog.xyz/dashboard/dashboard.js:114:9)
    at /home/dh_vemh38/thepog.xyz/dashboard/dashboard.js:170:5
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/dh_vemh38/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/home/dh_vemh38/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/home/dh_vemh38/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/dh_vemh38/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /home/dh_vemh38/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/home/dh_vemh38/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/home/dh_vemh38/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at SendStream.error (/home/dh_vemh38/node_modules/serve-static/index.js:121:7)
    at SendStream.emit (node:events:394:28)
    at SendStream.error (/home/dh_vemh38/node_modules/send/index.js:270:17)
    at SendStream.onStatError (/home/dh_vemh38/node_modules/send/index.js:421:12)
    at next (/home/dh_vemh38/node_modules/send/index.js:763:28)
```

it says that it cant lookup the views directory, was it renamed deleted or anything? no because there is no even views directory. which leaves me at confusion why is it searching for a views directory while it was never called?

**extra information:**
hosting on dreamhost https://www.dreamhost.com/
enabled node js passenger
installed node v16.5.0 and npm v7.19.1
installed all the modules
put in correct configurations
github repo https://github.com/MrAugu/simple-discordjs-dashboard/

Comment: have you configured your express server to locate views directory? `app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));` ?

Comment: also, which template engine are you using?

Comment: im using ejs and yes i did configure that however i dont want the views folder, the content is inside the templates folder and i used ```app.use("/", express.static(path.resolve(`${dataDir}${path.sep}assets`)));```

Comment: which is the code in the github repo i  didnt edit anything except minor page edits and configurations

Comment: to render the content i used ```app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    renderTemplate(res, req, "index.ejs");
  });``` for everypage

Comment: ejs requires your view engine configuration set, if your templates are under the templates folder, then configure your view engine as `app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'templates'));`

Comment: Yes, it's fine if you took it from github, it seems to me that the code on github was using older version of ejs and the one you installed now is updated version. So you need to follow the rules of the version you've installed. Which is why this configuration is required

Comment: i actually downgraded my npms all do the version that was working but still same error